# Getting type definition for nullable types breaks code for non-nullable types

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, nullable

This is a follow-up question to the following if you would like to see: [Parse to Nullable Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764041/parse-to-nullable-enum)

```
Type t = currentProperty.PropertyType;
if (t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
    t = t.GetGenericArguments().First();
```

I am getting an error on line #2 which is the IF statement.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the 
target of an invocation. ----> System.InvalidOperationException : This operation 
is only valid on generic types.
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
```

How can I test for that condition before executing the code in the IF statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is the MSDN documentation on checking for nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx)

It looks like you need to add the following:

```
if(t.IsGenericType && ...
```

Comment: Why the removal of the upvote though? Did this not answer your specific question?