# How to parse a null to a null in Enum.Parse?

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
return (Skills) Enum.Parse(typeof(Skills),  CSData[(int)cs].Requirement);
```

But since sometimes there is no requirement (ie value is null) i want in that case to parse the value null as well, how can i do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764041/parse-to-nullable-enum look at this SO posting

Answer (score 7):

The thing is, enums are *non-nullable* value types. So, logically, you can't "parse a null to a null", as you put it.

What you can do, is change the return type of your method to a nullable `Skills`.

```
public Skills? MyMethod(string str)
{
    return (str == null)
           ? null as Skills?
           : (Skills) Enum.Parse(typeof(Skills), str);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Enum.TryParse instead - it returns a boolean telling you whether the parsing worked rather than throwing an exception.  You can then act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [dcastros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24245111/1409903) answer you can introduce an additional enum value e.g. `Skills.Unknown` to avoid further checking for null in your code.

```
return String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? Skills.Unknown : (Skills)Enum.Parse(typeof(Skills), str);
```

Comment: but at that point couldnt i just use Unknown as string to pass?

Comment: @user3161621 When you are in control of how the data is parsed(or written) into your, lets call it, 'storage' then: Yes you can just pass "Unknown" as a parameter. But in the case that your data is from some kind of '3rd party' you obviously have to check for irregular values (which was kinda your original question).